# Flattening a mixture of lists and single elements in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, f#, flatten

In F# I can use the `yield`/`yield!` syntax in order to concat a mixture of single elements and arrays into a single collection, e.g.

```ml
let result = seq {
    yield 1
    yield! [2;3;4;5]
    yield! [6;7]
    yield 8
}

printfn "%A" result
// Prints: seq [1; 2; 3; 4; ...]
```

I'm wondering if there's a similar way of doing this in Haskell.

Comment: For single elements at the beginning, you can prepend with `1 : rest`. For the rest, you can use `concat` or `++`, I think.

Comment: Yeah, I know this method. I was wondering if there's anything fancier using e.g. list of comprehension that would look like the F# version.

Comment: `concat [[1], [2,3,4,5], [6,7], [8]]` ?

Comment: It would work, but I'd need to turn my single elements into lists first.

Comment: Anyway, I think that answers my question: this F# syntax doesn't have an equivalent in Haskell. Thanks guys!

Comment: You're already turning your single elements into lists! What do you think `yield` does?

Comment: Besides, this is more concise than the F# version, even if it isn't exactly baked into the syntax.

Comment: Actually, you're right, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equivalent would be:

```
result = concat [
     [1],
     [2,3,4,5],
     [6,7],
     [8]
  ]
```

Your comment:

> It would work, but I'd need to turn my single elements into lists first.

kinda misses the point. Your F# version is *already* turning single elements into lists. That's what `yield` does.

But if you're *really* hung up on the syntax, you can replicate it very closely with the writer monad:

```hs
import Control.Monad.Writer

yield x = tell [x]
yield' = tell

result = execWriter do
  yield 1
  yield' [2,3,4,5]
  yield' [6,7]
  yield 8
```